# Fake sudo script not working as expected

Tags: shell

I tried to fake a sudo program that requires real superuser password:

```
#!/bin/sh

su -c "'$*'"
```

It works when I do

```
sudo yum
```

But does not work when I do

```
sudo yum upgrade
```

Or any command that has arguments. Bash complains

```
bash: yum upgrade command not found
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quoting incorrectly.  This is the rare case where you actually want `"$*"` instead of `"$@"`.  But you definitely do not want `"'$*'"`

Comment: What is the difference of $@ and $*? And why cannot add single quotes? Cuz i always do **su -c 'yum upgrade'**

Comment: Using $@ gives distinct words, so if you call the sript with arguments `yum upgrade`, `su -c "$@"` is equivalent to `sudo -c "yum" "upgrade"`, but `su -c "$*"` is the same as `su -c "yum upgrade"`.  Using single quotes as you have is equivalent to `su -c "'yum upgrade'"`, so rather than running the command "yum" with the argument 'upgrade', su looks for a command named 'yum upgrade' and cannot find it.

Comment: Linking [What is the difference between $* and $@](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22589032/2311167) to this question